# Не работает text-align: justify; в firefox

Tags: html, css, вёрстка

Имеется файл со стилями `main.css` и файл `normalize.css`
Также имеется страница поста с заголовком и текстом, когда пытаюсь задать правило text-align: justify; работает везде, кроме firefox, НО если я сделаю эту страницу **(без нормалайза)** в онлайн редакторе *(codepen и др)*, то все работает.
Может эта проблема именно в `normalize` файле, но когда я использовал это раньше, все работало.

Файл `normalize.css` - [КЛИК](https://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/8.0.1/normalize.css) /
Файл `main.css` - *см. ниже*

```
.post{
    box-shadow: var(--shadow); // тут переменная 
    background-color: #fff;
    border-radius: 5px;
}
.post>.container{
    padding: 1em;
}
.post>.container>.title{ // это заголовок
    font-size: 2.5em;
    margin-top: 0;
    margin-bottom: .2em;
}
.post>.container>.text{ // Это текст
    white-space: pre-wrap;
    font-size: 20px;
    text-align: justify !important; // Тут проблема
}
```

**UPD. Убрал файл `normalize.css` все по прежнему не работает.**

Comment: Приведите [mcve] и удалите стили, которые не имеют отношения к проблеме

Comment: А вообще https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30887273

Comment: Когда приводил кусок кода убрал white-space и все заработало

Comment: Но все равно спасибо большое!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Убрал `white-space: pre-wrap;`, т. к. она мне серавно не нужна и все заработало ;D